# Nesting resources in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, rest, angularjs, restful-architecture, ngresource

I'm creating the "Discussions" module of my website with AngularJS.

I've actually two types of resources for client<->server communication :

1. **Discussion** *$resource* (used to retrieve Discussion-related infos, like 'title', 'status', etc. Discussions also contain an array of Message.
2. **Message** *$resource*

The problem : 
When I load the page, I do a *Discussion.query()*, for retrieving discussion title, etc. In order to economize client<->server requests, **the messages** of the discussion are also returned (in addition to **Discussion** info). 
Well, that's great, but what if I want to edit or delete messages ? As I got them using "**Discussion**" model object, messages are not considered as $resource **Message** and I can't *$update* them or *$delete them.

Actually, I could just do a "*Messages.get()*" for getting real Messages *$resources*, but it would cost a new request to my server (latency, SQL query, ...).

Currently, I found two workarounds for achieving that :

1. Using **Message** *$resource* static methods (*Message.delete(...)*, etc)
2. "Raw" *$http* requests

I'm not satisfied by these two solutions, because I want a code as simple as possible.

--

Is it possible to tell to Angular "hey this object is actually a Message $resource !" when I retrieve messages using another resource ?
Sorry for strange explanations. I don't think any code would help, but ask me I needed.

Comment: it sounds like the discussion service should have a dep on the messages service and it should set the .messages property on messagesService when it loads discussions; not familiar with $resource, so didn't leave a full answer

Comment: Yes I already did this. The problem is that resulting messages are not considered as $resource, so I can't edit/delete them

Comment: Post some code ... Is hard to follow what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a duplicate of this question here: [ngResource resolving nested resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406442/ngresource-resolving-nested-resources/19407120#comment28830398_19407120)

But to summarize: there isn't really a great way to do what you want using `$resource`.  Check out that post and the possible solutions I suggested, but as you can see, we never really came up with a good solution.

You can also check out the [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) library to see if that will fit your needs.